# Method missing when config.cache_classes = true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two ActiveRecord model called Scope and ScopeItem, with a has_many relationship:

```
class Scope < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scope_items
end

class ScopeItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scope
end
```

I also have a rake task for a background job to load a bunch of scope (reference) data:

```
  task :scopes => :environment do  
      scope = Scope.create!(
          # params
      )
      5.times do |n|
        scope.scope_items.create!({
          # more params
        })
      end
    end
  end
```

The rake task runs fine in development, but when I move to a staging/production setup, the task fails, saying Scope does not have a method called scope_items.

I compared the settings in the two environments, and determined experimentally that I can reproduce the error in development if I change the following setting:

```
# development.rb
config.cache_classes = false 

# !development.rb
config.cache_classes = true # all others use this
```

It seems to me the load path changes when this setting is turned on.  Is this true, and if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: It may be relevant where in the file structure these classes are defined.

Comment: I'm wondering if `scope` or `Scope` may be reserved words? Does it make any difference if you rename the local var from `scope` to something else? Or, can you add a debugger and make sure `Scope` is an instance of the class you expect it to be? If not, you can further test your theory in development mode by loading the ScopeItem class ahead at the beginning of the rake task. That is, just insert `ScopeItem` above `scope = Scope.create ...`. Does it still fail this way (with `config.cache_classes = false` in development)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a workaround for the rake task by adding the following:

```
My::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
end
load "#{Rails.root}/app/models/scope.rb"
```

This tickles the environment to reload the scope class, and the task runs fine.

pbobb may have been on to something with the reserved word thing, although it's bizarre that the app would still work in all environments otherwise.