# Is Ruby garbage collecting my classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection, autoload

I have a Rails app where I some times see `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo` errors in some heavy rake tasks. `Foo` varies, but it's app-level classes, such as models or services from `/lib/` etc. The task uses `Process.fork` for some parts, so I first though this might be the culprit, but these errors happens outside as well as inside the fork. I now suspect that classes may be autoloaded by Rails and then later disposed of by garbage collection. Does this sound plausible? And is there a way to avoid that happening?

Comment: Can you put this in the Ruby mailing list or [forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/forum/ruby) ? I am quite sure, we will be having very good discussion on this.

Comment: Sounds like some classes are **unloaded** by Rails.

Comment: What happens if you modify the value of [config.cache_classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644872/method-missing-when-config-cache-classes-true)?

Comment: Are your tasks multithreaded?

Comment: @FrederickCheung No, I only use fork.

Comment: @simonwo I'll give it a try. This doesn't happen in dev, so that might be relevant. Will post back here when I've tried it.

Comment: If you use fork, your app is multi-threaded.

Comment: @MarlinPierce Surely it's not? That will spawn a new process, not a new thread. It'll be parallel, but as far as I understand, each process will be a fully independent clone of the original process, yes?

Comment: @troelskn Both multi-processes and multi-threads are often called multi-threaded because the same race conditions and synchronization issues arise.  Some OSes do all their multi-threading with processes.